# Can't delete a section in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, edit, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to remove a certain part in a WordPress theme, but can't find a way to do so.

I tried customizing it (Appearance -> Customize), but that didn't work. Also I tried finding the code of it in order to delete it: Appearance -> Editor, but that didn't work either.

Here is the link of the website: http://ojqmbeshtetja.com/. The part is the green picture on the bottom with the words "Ballina" on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add `body.home.page .wrap-inner-banner {display:none}` as the temporary  solution. you can find the original settings at the theme customization

Comment: Hello. I reset the whole wordpress database because it started giving me way too many other errors, but thank you very much for your answer. I will save this if I encounter this problem again :)